# GUI visuals not shown when running emacs as daemon

Tags: user-interface, emacs, daemon

I'm using multimonitor workstation and need emacs running as daemon to assure correct working with multiple frames, for example to avoid ending emacs session after closing a frame.

When I run emacs as daemon I face problem with visuals that usually displays in GUI. Icons and connectors for the dirtree mode and same things for the sr-speedbar mode are replaced with ascii pseudo-graphics as I run emacs under console.

How can I enable GUI visuals even for daemonized emacs?

running emacs as daemon:

```
emacs --daemon=foo
```

spawning emacs frames:

```
emacsclient -c -s foo
emacsclient -c -s foo
emacsclient -c -s foo
```

All commands are run from GUI where `DISPLAY` variable is set

Comment: What do you mean by "running emacs as a daemon"? Running an emacs server and use emacs gui clients to connect to said server?

Comment: added commands for emacs invocation

Comment: Maybe put a screenshot to show your problem as it is not clear.